# Inequalities involving the existence of a constant factor

Tags: inequality

Prove that there exists a positive real number $c$ such that $x + y \ge c\min\{x, y\}$ for every two positive integers $x, y$.

Prove that $\forall c \in \mathbb R_+$, $\exists p \in \mathbb Z_+$, $\forall n \in \mathbb Z_+, n \ge p \rightarrow n \le c n^{2}$.

I'm stuck with these last 2; thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, in the future, please ask one question per post.

Comment: For the first inequality take $c=1$. The second  means that the sequence $(\frac{1}{n})$ converges to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

1) This one seems quite easy ... maybe too easy. $c=1$ always does the job, and the proof seems trivial

2) The second one doesn't seem much harder, just make a distinction between $c > 1$ ( in this case $p=1$ always work ) and $c\in(0,1)$ ( $1<=cp$ , aka pick the first integer greater than $1/c$  )